# Animating several SVGs Paths - performance recommendation

Tags: javascript, svg, inline-svg

I have several SVGs on my page, maybe a max of 10-15.They are not particularly complex an example of a path maybe the below:

```
<path d="M79.7315 149.8506 a248.48549470442975 248.48549470442975 0 0 0 462.2685 -51.850599999999986a229.28617885359205 229.28617885359205 0 0 1 -427.2987 40.6302M79.7315 149.8506 a75 75 0 1 1 34.969800000000006 -11.220399999999984"></path>
```

Its basically a speech bubble which will come from someones mouth so really just several arcs, maybe some lines, compared to some I've seen its nothing.

However on my pages, when the mouse moves paths get updated (they change significantly, but still are the same sort of shape, so the path isn't any bigger).  I can notice a significant performance hit when this is occurring on a mobile device such as an Ipad and theres 3+ of them on the page.

I assumed this was down to my calculations to get the new path, however I have used the chrome tools (performance tab) and it seems like me settings the attribute is contributing a fair bit.  So my question...

When the mouse moves its doing a

element.attr("d", newPath);

as mentioned this is occurring to maybe 15 separate svgs.

Is there a more efficient way of setting the path?
Is there a method to set the path of each, but only call the repaint/update once?

many thanks

Comment: You could try doing the animation via SMIL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you animating this with Javascript? If you want really smooth animations you might try CSS animations. Unless you have an extremely complex motion in mind, you should be able to just set the beginning and end attributes, and it will smoothly animate (using the easing function of your choice). There are plenty of tutorials online, here's one: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/css-animation-for-beginners

Comment: You can't CSS animate a path, only via SMIL or javascript animation.

Comment: Sure you can! SVG elements can be accessed just like any normal HTML element: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lcq8bpz/
Also it sounds like SMIL is being considered for deprecation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL

Comment: SMIL's deprecation was cancelled as that article indicates if you read the second sentence and CSS can't animate attributes, only CSS properties. Only Chome supports paths as CSS properties so far. Safari and Firefox don't. Do feel free to try it.